# What is the best way to clear an array of strings?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

What is the best way to clear an array of strings?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Wrong way:

```
myArray = Nothing
```

Only sets the variable pointing to the array to nothing, but doesn't actually clear the array. Any other variables pointing to the same array will still hold the value. Therefore  it is necessary to clear out the array.

Correct Way

```
Array.Clear(myArray,0,myArray.Length)
```

Comment: *slow round of applause for cerebrus* that makes it MUCH more understandable :)

Comment: That doesn't clear the array - it sets the variable to Nothing. Anything else referring to the same array will still see the existing values.

Comment: Thanks ... I had actually done the Array.clear, but something was telling me there was a more efficiant short hand way .... not end of the world stuff, but was really bugging me lunch time

Answer (score 7):

And of course there's the VB way using the Erase keyword:

```
Dim arr() as String = {"a","b","c"}
Erase arr
```

Comment: +1 for the VBism, but, unfortunately, `Erase` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9.aspx) to be the same as just setting the variable(s) to `Nothing`. It doesn't clear the array.

Answer (score 2):

Depending what you want:

- Assign Nothing (null)
- Assign a new (empty) array
- Array.Clear

Last is likely to be slowest, but only option if you don't want a new array.

Answer (score 2):

If you're needing to do things like clear, you probably want a *collection* like `List(Of String)`  rather than an array.

Comment: Good point, but existing array ... cann't split a string into a list of strings in one command can you ?

Comment: No, but you could call .ToList() on the result of String.Split.

Answer (score 1):

redim arr(1,1,1,1)
and then
redim (z,x,y,v) to your dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple call that I use to clear the contents of a string array:

```
Public Sub ClearArray(ByRef StrArray As String())
    For iK As Int16 = 0 To StrArray.Length - 1
        StrArray(iK) = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Then just call it with:

```
ClearArray(myLocalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reinitialize with empty strings or other values not equal to Nothing/Null, you may get further using an extension method:

```
Option Strict On : Option Explicit On : Option Infer On
...
Public Delegate Sub ArrayForAllDelegate(Of T)(ByRef message As T)
<Extension>
Public Function ForAll(Of T)(ByRef self As T(), f As ArrayForAllDelegate(Of T)) As T()
    Dim i = 0
    While i < self.Length
        f(self(i))
        i += 1
    End While
    Return self
End Function
```

Then your initialization code:

```
Dim a = New String(3 - 1) {"a", "b", "c"}
...
a.ForAll(Sub(ByRef el) el = "") 'reinitialize the array with actual empty strings
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
Redim myarray(-1)
```