# Reset an Array to Default in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: arrays, vb.net, erase

What is the code to reset an array to its default state so that all the elements are erased?

Comment: I'm no VB expert so won't attempt any sample code, but [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.100).aspx) comes to mind as a starting point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vba: clear entire array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018510/vba-clear-entire-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to clear an array of strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713867/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try [Array.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
Array.Clear(myArray, 0, myArray.Length)
```

that will revert value of each array element to default (`0`, `false`, or `Nothing` depending on the element type as described in the link above).

Another option is to use [Erase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9.aspx)

```
Erase myArray
```

that will turn `myArray` variable to `Nothing`.

Comment: thanks, I use erase but when I do, and I try to reuse the array, I get value cannot be null error

Comment: yep as pointed above, it turns to `Nothing`. So you need to reinitialize the array before assigning new value to the array element. If you don't want to reinit, go with `Array.Clear` option.

Comment: where i put myArray.Length, what if the array has no bounds such as Names()

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure I get the question, if your array is `Names()` then you can do `Array.Clear(Names, 0, Names.Length)`. `Length` is a built in property of array that indicates it's size/length

Comment: oh ok I thought you had to declare the size of the array there. All fixed, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Erase`.

```
Erase YourArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Array.Clear(Array, 0, Array.length)
```

You can switch 0 to Nothing it depends on the variable in your array