# Array.Clear throwing out of bounds exception

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm having trouble with a clear statement. I've got an array that gets sized dynamically, filled, and then passed to a function to be converted to some custom objects.

After that conversion I want to clear the array. I use

`Array.Clear(FileData, 0, FileData.Length)`

as this thread suggests ([reset-an-array-to-default-in-visual-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643228/reset-an-array-to-default-in-visual-basic-2010)). However, every time I get to that point in the script the try-catch wrapping the Clear catches an out of bounds exception on the Clear.

The array is not empty (actually it's got ~34900 items) so it's not that the array has zero length. The one thing that it might be that isn't discussed in the question I referenced above is that my array is 2 dimensional.

All that said, I'm fairly well stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: For those experiencing this issue, I ultimately just left the step commented out, so that instead of clearing and then setting the array to Nothing, I just set it to Nothing. Doesn't really solve the underlying issue, but (should) free up memory all the same.

Comment: What is each of its dimensions?

Comment: Unknown. The array of arrays is used to take in the data from a CSV whose number of columns and rows varies (our customer doesn't manage the db that generates the CSVs very well). So to deal with their craziness I find the "corners" of the data in the CSV, and then dump the whole thing into FileData. I then convert each element in FileData into a specified object so that everything is all nice an cleaned up for import to a relational db that we have

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? That's the only explanation I can come up with. And as David mentioned in his answer. If you need resizable stores, consider using generic lists.

Comment: No threading (no where near good enough to be messing with threading). Lists are out due to the fact the column orders can change, from one dump to the next. I do throw the objects created from each element into a list

Comment: Approximately, I mean.

Comment: Could you please add the declaration of `FileData`?

Comment: Is `FileData` a jagged array?

Comment: minitech: It's pretty hard to say, in some instances the dumps come in 5 chunks, other times it's one massive file. In the first instance, some chunks are as small as 200-500 elements in FileData and others are 1000+. In the one file scenario there are ~3000 rows in the CSV. ANDREW: Probably not, but I've not done the checking to be sure. NICO: FileData is declared as a Public Property of an object I use to ferry data throughout the script: `Public Property FileData as Object(,) = Nothing`

Comment: For those who come across this thread in the future, I still haven't figured out an actual solution. All I did to get past the problem was to comment out the Clear statements and simply set the array to Nothing.